# 2sxc Get list of fields of an entity

Tags: c#, dotnetnuke, 2sxc

Let's say I have an entity "Cars" with two fields "Brand" and "Model".

In a c# template, is it possible to dynamically get the name of the fields inside "Cars" to a list? The output would meed to be {"Brand", "Model"}.

Even further, is it possible to get the description and a specific translation of the field name and description?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Daniel's comments and circling around to just answer your original question, here it is simplified and things are split up a little to see the parts:

```
@inherits ToSic.Sxc.Dnn.RazorComponent
@using Newtonsoft.Json

@{
    var myData = AsList(Data);
    var myDatum = AsEntity(myData.First());
    var myFieldNames = (myDatum.Type.Attributes as IEnumerable<dynamic>).Select(a => a.Name);

}
<pre>
myDatum.Type.Name = @myDatum.Type.Name
myFieldNames = @JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myFieldNames)
</pre>
```

Which then outputs just:

```
myDatum.Type.Name = Cars
myFieldNames = ["Name","Brand","Model"]
```

Comment: oh, and if you get an error about IEnumerable<>, you probably just need to add `@using System.Collections.Generic` up at the top so it know where to find it.

Comment: Cool - I like it 

Comment: Great. For an all code solution, we can start with 
var myData = AsList(App.Data["Cars"]);

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are trying to do is covered in the tutorials pretty well.
https://2sxc.org/dnn-tutorials/en/razor

In particular take a look at the LINQ examples; numbers 6, 7, and 8.

Comment: I can't find anything that resembles what I need.

Answer (score 1):

I @Joao

Basically you should check Jeremys answer for most of your question.

I believe you're also asking about showing the labels like `Brand` in the Razor using the field-label from the `ContentType` specs. This is possible, but it's a bit harder as it's not a common use case. So let me just point you in the right direction...

Each entity has a property called `Type`. In Razor you would get this using

`var someType = AsEntity(yourThing).Type;`

This is an `IContentType` https://docs.2sxc.org/api/dot-net/ToSic.Eav.Data.IContentType.html.

To get the properties and the names of them you would go to

`var attr = someType.Attributes["TheName"];`

which gives you an `IContentTypeAttribute` https://docs.2sxc.org/api/dot-net/ToSic.Eav.Data.IContentTypeAttribute.html

This has `Metadata` - so

`var attr = someType.Attributes["TheName"].Metadata;`

The metadata is an `IMetadataOf` https://docs.2sxc.org/api/dot-net/ToSic.Eav.Metadata.IMetadataOf.html

So using this you can find everything you want - but as you can see it's quite a hoop to jump through.

Comment: All your links go 404

Comment: Since I'm not quite understanding the answers, I'll assum my question was not clear.
I do not need the content of the table/entity. I need the name of the fields existing in that table. I need to supply the table name ("Cars") to the code and expect the return of all field names existing in that table (not the content/data).

Comment: I just clicked on all the links above, they are working from here (Central Coast of the US).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple working example. I am sorta hoping Daniel chimes in and reveals an easy way to go from myType.Attributes and convert straight to a Json string??

Create a new View, Enable List, point it to your Cars Content-Type, fix the last few lines so that the "And the data..." part matches your CT's actual fields.

```
@inherits ToSic.Sxc.Dnn.RazorComponent

@{
    var myData = AsList(Data);
    var myType = AsEntity(myData.First()).Type;
    var myFields = new List<string>();
    foreach(var field in myType.Attributes) {
        myFields.Add(field.Name);
    }
}
<div @Edit.TagToolbar(Content)>
    <h3>View Heading</h3>
    <h4>Table (Content Type) Name: @myType.Name</h4>
    <p>has the following fields</p>
    <div class="d-flex flex-row bd-highlight mb-3">
@foreach(var field in myType.Attributes) {
        <p class="p-2 bd-highlight"><strong>@field.Name</strong></p>
}
    </div>

    <h4>As a comma separated list?</h4>
    <p>@string.Format("{{\"{0}\"}}", string.Join("\",\"", myFields))</p>

    <h4>And the data...</h4>
@foreach(var cont in AsList(Data)) {

    <div class="d-flex flex-row bd-highlight mb-3"
        @Edit.TagToolbar(cont)>
        <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">@cont.EntityId</div>
        <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">@cont.Name</div>
        <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">@cont.Brand</div>
        <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">@cont.Model</div>
    </div>
}
</div>
```

The Cars Content type with only 3 fields
[image]

And the output of the View looks like this
[image]

Comment: 1. The first block of code can be simplified using LINQ to  `var myFields = AsEntity(myData.First()).Type.Attributes.Select(a => a.Name);`

Comment: 2. To create good JSON you should use Newtonsoft - it's part of every DNN installation and 2sxc uses it too.

Comment: 3. If you ever want to show the fields dynamically, you can use the new Get - so if you loop through the fields you can use `@cont.Get(fieldName)` - see https://docs.2sxc.org/api/dot-net/ToSic.Sxc.Data.IDynamicEntity.html#ToSic_Sxc_Data_IDynamicEntity_Get_System_String_

Comment: I did try the first example above `var myFields = AsEntity(myData.First()).Type.Attributes.Select(a => a.Name);` but I get an error: "Exception: Error in your code. Probably https://r.2sxc.org/ErrLambda can help. What follows is the internal error: ---> System.Web.HttpCompileException: c:\HostingSpaces\ASL\accu4.com\www\Portals\0\2sxc\Accu4\_Entity-Fields-Test.cshtml(12): error CS1977: Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type at ..."

Comment: And as you prolly already know, the fix was `var myFields = (AsEntity(myData.First()).Type.Attributes as IEnumerable<dynamic>).Select(a => a.Name);`

Answer (score 1):

For an update on what I needed to achieve, this outputs the field name and the label for an easy loop:

```
var myData = AsList(App.Data["Stages"]);
var myDatum = AsEntity(myData.First());
var myFields = (myDatum.Type.Attributes as IEnumerable<dynamic>);
// var myFieldNames = myFields.Select(a => a.Name);
// var myFieldLabels = myFields.Select(a => (a.Metadata as IEnumerable<dynamic>).First().Title.TypedContents);
var myFieldNamesAndLabels = myFields.Select(i => new 
{ 
  i.Name, 
  (i.Metadata as IEnumerable<dynamic>).First().GetBestTitle()
});
```

If there is an easier way to achieve this, please let me know.
Thanks @Jeremy Farrance and @iJungleBoy

Comment: error CS0746: Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access.